# Need to make selected in a CheckboxGroup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a `<CheckboxGroup>` as follows:

```
<CheckboxGroup name="permitted">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" />Orders
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" />Production
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" />Dispatch
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" />Returns
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" />Sundry
  <input type="checkbox" value="6" />Collection
  <input type="checkbox" value="7" />Pending Amount
  <input type="checkbox" value="8" />Pending Bills
  <input type="checkbox" value="9" />Ledger
  <input type="checkbox" value="10" />Day Book
</CheckboxGroup>
```

I am trying to make some of the checkboxes selected out of this,

Suppose I need Orders,Dispatch to be checked using jQuery.
I have the corresponding values 1,3 with me.

Check my fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mahhrrr7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select those using the attribute selector and use `.prop()` to check the checkboxes:

```
$('[value="1"], [value="3"]').prop("checked", true);
```

```js
$('[value="1"], [value="3"]').prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Orders
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />Production
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />Dispatch
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />Returns
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />Sundry
<input type="checkbox" value="6" />Collection
<input type="checkbox" value="7" />Pending Amount
<input type="checkbox" value="8" />Pending Bills
<input type="checkbox" value="9" />Ledger
<input type="checkbox" value="10" />Day Book
```

**Update**

From AJAX, you can do this way:

```js
$(function () {
  valuesFromAjax = "1,2";
  valuesFromAjax = valuesFromAjax.split(",");
  valuesFromAjax.map(function (Id) {
    $('[value="' + Id + '"]').prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Orders
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />Production
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />Dispatch
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />Returns
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />Sundry
<input type="checkbox" value="6" />Collection
<input type="checkbox" value="7" />Pending Amount
<input type="checkbox" value="8" />Pending Bills
<input type="checkbox" value="9" />Ledger
<input type="checkbox" value="10" />Day Book
```

Comment: thanks buddy. I have one more doubt I am getting 1,2 from ajax, is there any otherway so that I can directly pass this?

Comment: yes buddy you are spot on!! Yah it is getting as a String

Comment: this is what I am looking for. One more thing is there any way to reset all values I mean make all un selected before doing these. I am making it using a drop down so it needs to be reset first!!Suggest a way buddy

Comment: how can I reset all to unselected??

Comment: @Santhucool Simple. Use `$('input').prop("checked", false);` wherever you want!

Comment: I tried `$('.permitted').prop("checked", false);` that but not working. Thats why asked buddy sorry!!

Comment: What is `$('.permitted')`?

Comment: `<CheckboxGroup name="permitted">` checkbox group name

Comment: Give it this way: `$("CheckboxGroup[name='permitted'] :checkbox").prop("checked", false);` should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99698/discussion-between-santhucool-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the array has string values you can use the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //init an array with the values from OP
  var values = ["1", "3"];
  //iterate through each checkbox
  $("CheckboxGroup[name='permitted'] :checkbox").each(function() {
    //if value exist in array change the status of the checkbox
    $(this).prop("checked", values.indexOf(this.value) !== -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<CheckboxGroup name="permitted">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" />Orders
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" />Production
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" />Dispatch
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" />Returns
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" />Sundry
  <input type="checkbox" value="6" />Collection
  <input type="checkbox" value="7" />Pending Amount
  <input type="checkbox" value="8" />Pending Bills
  <input type="checkbox" value="9" />Ledger
  <input type="checkbox" value="10" />Day Book
</CheckboxGroup>
```